# How to cancel changes resulting from SQL query?

Tags: sql-server

Sometimes, I execute a query with wrong condition, and I must cancel changes that query made. I must restore the previous data.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't unless you have run that query in a transaction. `Rollback` would have saved you if you executed the query in transaction.

Or, check if there is scheduled backup. If so, There is a chance of rolling back to nearest data.